# Number from a string of numbers-prolog

Tags: string, binary, prolog, numbers

I would like to get a number within a string like
1100010 I would like to get the last two digits
How would I do that If I dunno the the length of the given String

```
forFun("",0).
forFun(Str,N) :- Str1 is Str - 1,
                 forFun(Str1,N1),
                 N is N1 + 1.
```

is that a possible code ?

Answer (score 1):

First (unfortunately) we need to agree what we mean by "string". For many purposes the best and most portable representation is a list of "chars" (one-character atoms), though your Prolog might need to be told that this is really the representation you want:

```
?- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).
true.
```

Now, for example:

```
?- Number = "12345".
Number = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'].
```

To get the last two elements of a list, you can use the widely supported (though not standard) `append/3` predicate. You can ask Prolog a question that amounts to "are there some list `_Prefix` (that I do not care about) and a two-element list `LastDigits` that, appended together, are equal to my `Number`?".

```
?- Number = "12345", LastDigits = [X, Y], append(_Prefix, LastDigits, Number).
Number = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
LastDigits = ['4', '5'],
X = '4',
Y = '5',
_Prefix = ['1', '2', '3'] ;
false.
```

The last two digits of this number are `['4', '5']`.